# What are the Session Sampling Limits for GA Premium Accounts in the V4 Reporting API?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

When using the v3 reporting API with GA Premium enabled properties, the number of sessions over the given date range where GA starts sampling is 1MM sessions. Using the web interface, I can currently run ad-hoc reports over 50MM sessions before GA starts returning sampled data (the [GA documentation](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2637192) states 25MM, but I have found that to be wrong).

I can't find any information on the v4 reporting API's sampling limits (free or premium/360). What is the largest number of sessions you have been able to query with the v4 API before sampling occurs?

Answer (score 0):

The v4 API should (in time) have the same sampling limits as the interface does. Right now however the API V4 limitations are still the same as the V3 limitations.

Google is said to be working on it, but I've not seen a timeline of when to expect this.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have a source for the V4 API's sample size limits, or is this based on your observations working with V4?